# What is this modification to two-port theory for bilateral amplifiers?

Tags: circuit-analysis, analog

In multiple textbooks I've consulted (e.g. *Microelectronic Circuits* by Sedra and Smith, or *Analysis and Design of Analog Integrated Circuits* by Gray, Hurst, Meyer, and Lewis) the authors seem to deviate from two-port theory in the following way when faced with a bilateral circuit (at the end of this post I give an example from Chapter 3 of GHML).

Rather than simply computing the four y-parameters of the two-port network in question, the authors instead append the input and load termination circuits (assuming the load is passive) and then compute \$R_i = 1/y_{11}\$, \$R_o = 1/y_{22}\$ and \$G_m = y_{21}\$ *while keeping these input and output termination circuits attached* (which is not what we do in two-port theory). They then seem to simply *take* \$y_{12} = 0\$ and represent the amplifier in terms of this "equivalent unilateral circuit". **Why is this a valid procedure? If it is an approximation to the actual bilateral circuit, what is the nature of the approximation?**

See here for a long discussion from GHML which does just this:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you asking about why we assumed that the amplifier is a unilateral device?

Comment: @G36 Sort of I guess. I'm finding it hard to phrase but I'm asking why we're taking this bilateral two-port network and then using this modification of two-port theory (wherein we include the load terminations) and we graft on a unilateral model.